# Should the composition root be transient or per-request when using ASP.NET with Castle Windsor?

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

Following the suggestion in "Dependency Injection in .NET", I am resolving the composition root in each page constructor like this:

```
public MyPageConstructor()
{
    var container = (Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer)HttpContext.Current.Application["DIcontainer"];
    Controller = container.Resolve<MyPageController>();
}
```

Now, if I make the controller transient, I have to release it manually when the page is unloaded. If I make it per-request, Castle will release it for me when the request is over but there may be a performance penalty, I am not sure. At the moment I tend to make the objects transient and handle the release on my own.

Are there other things to consider and what would be the recommended practice?

Thank you.

Comment: Instead of creating a hard dependency between your Page class and Castle, extract this to a special 'service locator' (for instance a create static `T Resolve<T>()` method inside the `Global.asax`. This allows you to remove that nasty first line of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to use the longest possible lifetime. Unfortunately, complex application can have more than one entry points, where the Resolve method has called. And if you chose Transient, there is a risk that some service would be created multiple times per request. For example, some HttpModule could use the same services, as a Page. With PerRequest lifetime such issue can be avoided.

Comment: Interesting ... if a page is executed more than once during a request, do I really want a single controller instance for both executions? I suppose there wouldn't be thread-safety issues, but how about inner states etc.?

Comment: You should try to design the stateless classes if it's possible. If not, then Transient is your choice. But there are other services, not only controllers.  I was talking in general. Longer lifetime is better, singleton lifetime is the best. Incidentally, the processing of the request is synchronous, so the PerRequest lifetime is thread-safe.

Comment: ok, now I understand, thank you. So in general PerRequest is better. In my specific scenario, where the controller is going to be invoked just once no matter if the lifestyle is transient or perRequest it probably doesn't matter thank much.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, if you have a class that has a lot of dependencies on it, the overhead of instantiating the same thing over and over, might be to severe. But if have something that isn't threadsafe you are better of as transient.

Comment: thanks, but the number of instances would be the same in both scenarios